# JSON Date format - display time only

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I have an application using Bootstrap tables and one of the fields is Time. When I get the data from the database, it is encoded in JSON format ad the data for this field is something like 2016-11-07T13:40:29.000Z which I understand is the standard JSON format.

I'd like to break it apart and have one column in my table display the date and another column display the time, ideally. But I would be happy if I could just get the Time column to display only time.

I've read that is has something to do with adding a dataFormatter to the column header, but I can't seem to make it work, as my javascript returns NaN.

This is the code I found while researching the problem. I'm new to Javascript, so there is probably a few mistakes here that I would appreciate some help with.

```
<table id="table"  data-url ="http://maccdx161012:4567/api/v1/sat" data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>

           <th data-field="initials">Initials</th>
            <th data-field="sector">Sector</th>
            <th data-field="cjs">CJS</th>
            <th data-field="satin" data-formatter="timeFormatter">In</th> 
            <th data-field="satout">Out</th> 
            <th data-field="duration">Duration</th> 
            <th data-field="position">Position</th>
            <th data-field="ot">OT</th>             
        </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
<script>
    function timeFormatter(value) {
        var date = new Date(value*1000);
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();

        return hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `'2016-11-07T13:40:29.000Z'.substring(11,16)`

Comment: If you are seeing a NaN exception, probably 'value' input field is not a date, you can put a console.log(value) in your function to see what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    function timeFormatter(value) {
        var date = new Date(value);
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = leadZero(date.getMinutes());

        return hours + ':' + minutes;
    }
    function dateFormatter(value) {
        var date = new Date(value);
        var years = date.getFullYear();
        var months = leadZero(date.getMonth() + 1);
        var days = leadZero(date.getDate());

        return years + '-' + months + '-' + days;
    }
    function leadZero(n) { return n>9 ? n : "0" + n; }
</script>
```

It will return time for your local timezone. If you don't want this feature - use  Keith's solution.

Comment: This seems to work exactly as I wanted, with one problem. I have one time that looks like this: 16:39 or 15:32 which is great. But some of them look like this: 16:0 or 18:0. Any idea why this may be happening to some but not all? When I remove the code and go back to JSON format, they all look the same. Thanks again!! It really helped

Comment: It appears it may have something to do with times where the minutes are less than 10.

Comment: Try new version

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: I hate to ask, but I will :) How would I retrieve just the date portion and display it as 2016-11-11 for example?

Comment: I've updated code in my answer. You can also use `leadZero` for `hours` if you need